# it is possible to change which field to display on the calendar when creating an event?

Tags: community, event, calendar

I need to display on the calendar another text field, but by default subject its shown. It is possible to change it to Account name or another field?

[image: picture related]

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid not.

However, you can hover over a calendar record and see additional information. You can even change which fields appear there and include your text field.

To customize it, go to **Setup->Object Manager ->Event -> Compact Layouts** and edit the System Default record or create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The Lightning Calendar now shows more than just the Subject. It also shows one other field according to this precedence rule:

1. Show the contents of the Name field (e.g. a Contact) if it's not empty;
2. Else show the contents of the Related-To field (e.g. an Account) if it's not empty;
3. Else show nothing additional.

This behavior can't be customized.